# Is there a way to easily add className to all tags in JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I've been told that I shouldn't use HTML tags to style it in the CSS but rather use classes. Okay, not a problem I'll just add className to the tags. However there are quite a few of them in the code, so I was just wondering if there was a better way than just copy pasting the className into each tag or if there's a way to say for example all p tags should have class "text".

Comment: "I've been told that I shouldn't use HTML tags to style it in the CSS but rather use classes." — That's bad advice

Comment: "if there's a way to say for example all p tags should have class "text"." — If you do that then there's no difference, other than specificity, between `.text` and `p` so its pointless and doesn't solve any problem that using class selectors instead of type selectors would solve in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

if all `p` tags should have a particular style then you should highly consider styling all the p tags directly via CSS

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Your Styles here */
}

p.specific {
  font-size: 24px;
  /* Override styles for specific elements here */
}
```

Now answering the actual question. This can be done via JavaScript but once again **I don't recommend this** as this will have serious performance issues if there are a lot of nodes on the page.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("p").forEach(p => p.classList.add("text"));
```

Since you have tagged this as react, you can also extract the paragraph into its own component

```
const P = ({ children }) => {
  return <p className="text">{children}</p>;
};
```

Comment: Yea, that's how I did it before, then I got the feedback that I should use classes over targeting all p tags

Comment: JSX is typically used in combination with React where direct DOM manipulation like this is likely to cause sync issues. This isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Quentin The answer already mentions that it is not recommended to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either add class to all elements like Mailk suggested.

```
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(p => p.classList.add("text"));
```

or you can simply find and replace all the p tags using the text editor.

find: <p

replace to: <p className="text"

Comment: Yea I was afraid that just using the text editor would be the best to do, was hoping for a cool react feature where just said "all p tags now have className text". Thanks for the input

Comment: JSX is typically used in combination with React where direct DOM manipulation like this is likely to cause sync issues. This isn't a good idea.